# Overload postfix increment operator

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Suppose I have a class `Foo` and I want to to overload the postfix increment operator. I do something like:

```
class Foo{
.....
public:
   friend Foo& operator++(Foo&, int);
```

and then I define the new operator somewhere. What I really cannot figure out is where does this `int` come from.

If I have:  `f = Foo();` I can do:

```
f++;
```

and this seems to me to be unary.

How is the syntactic rule?

In the tests I ran the int value passed was `0`. Is ti always zero?

Comment: It is basically a means to distinguish between postfix and prefix.

Comment: Conventionally, postfix returns by value, not by reference.

Answer (score 1):

int parameter is just a convention, hint for the compiler to differentiate between prefix and postfix operators.

Comment: more than just a hint, and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6s9k9ta(v=vs.100).aspx) indicates using anything other than int is an error.